# Update/reload specific div when there is a new data inserted in the database. Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want a way to make a div works like (real-time), when the database change automatic update the div. I saw a method that sets interval every x seconds to refresh the div but I think it is a bad practice because it causes a strain in the server. I also saw laravel pusher and socket.io but I thinks its too hard for me. I want to use simple codes and not using some package for now. Can someone help me with this?

shownews.blade.php (where the comments are shown in div commentarea)

```
                  <h4 class="comments-title" > <span class="fas fa-comment-alt"></span>
                    {{$news->comments()->count()}}
                    Comments</h4>
                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px;
                      width: 400px; " id="commentarea" >

                          @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
                            <div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" >
                          <div class="author-info">
                              <img src={{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=retro" }} class="author-image" id="image">

                              <div class="author-name">
                                   <h4>{{$comment->name}} </h4>
                                   <p class="author-time"> {{  date('F nS, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="comment-content">
                                    {{$comment->comment}}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          @endforeach
                      </div>
                  </div>



 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
               jQuery.ajax({
                  url: 'article' + {{$news->id}} ,
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {
                     name: jQuery('#name').val(),
                     email: jQuery('#email').val(),
                     comment: jQuery('#comment').val()
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                      //console.log(data);
                  }});
               });
            });

    </script>
```

CommentsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use App\News;
use App\Graph;
use Validator;
use Session;




class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, $news_id)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name'=> 'required | max:255',
            'email'=> 'required| email | max:255',
            'comment'=> 'required | min:5'
        ));

        $news = News::find($news_id);

        $comment = new Comment();

        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->approved = true;
        $comment->news()->associate($news);

        $comment->save();
        // return response()->json($comment);

        return redirect()->route('article', [$news->id]);

    }
}
```

Comment.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'comment',
    ];
    //
    public function news(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News');
    }
}
```

News.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class news extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'subtitle', 'body', 'image',
    ];


    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to achieve this is to have some form of websocket you can listen on (socket.io or Pusher) without having the div refresh every X seconds. Socket.io can be a little complicated but the Laravel-Websocket package it a really nice self hosting pusher replacement. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwAKR305CRO9rlj-U9oOi4m2sQaWN6XA8

Comment: it cant be done sir using ajax or jquery? @Petay87

Comment: Yes, if you want to update the DIV without updating the entire page, you will NEED to use Ajax. However, you still need to know when to trigger the refresh if you don't want it to happen every X seconds. So you need the websocket to listen for the event to trigger this.

Comment: is there any ajax or jquery function that it will only trigger to change the div content when there is a new data added in the database? so in that way the div will only change if there is a new data inserted.

Comment: OK, so you could run an Ajax every X seconds but only update the DIV if the response indicates there is a difference in the data being returned.

Comment: you think it is a good alternative sir than using websockets? and how to do that sir?

Comment: I think it's your only real alternative but it's still not great as every client that has the page open is going to put extra resource contention on your web and DB server every X seconds. You just need to find away to detect the changes in the controller.

Comment: Im new to laravel sir and I dont know how to find a way to detect some changes in the database using the controller. Could you help me about it?